# XSL:FO Page-Number() function with leading zeros

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, xsl-fo

Lets say I want to print a page number   "01" as two separate digits 0 and 1 from 1 to 9 
0X-> 01,02,03....
from 10 to 99
10,11,12

```
<fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="TableCellBorder">
    <fo:block>
      <xsl:value-of select="substring(<fo:page-number/>, 1, 1)"/> //0 or first page-number digit
    </fo:block>
</fo:table-cell>
<fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="TableCellBorder">
   <fo:block>
      <xsl:value-of select="substring(<fo:page-number/>, 2, 1)"/>//second page-number digit
    </fo:block>
</fo:table-cell>
```

any ideas how to do this?

Comment: There is no `Page-Number()` function. There is only the `<fo:page-number/>` formatting object.

Comment: This question is rather badly worded. If all you wanted was page numbers formatted so that they are at least two digits long, then why didn't you say so? As I said in my answer, what you attempt to do in the code snippet (using `substring()` on `<fo:page-number/>`) cannot work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<fo:page-sequence master-reference="mymaster" format="01">
  ...
    <fo:page-number/>
  ...
</fo:page-sequence>
```

Described [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#convert), the only trick is figuring out where to place it.

Sorry, tested with XEP only; no idea if FOP supports it.

**UPD**. Would you consider adding the words of "leading zeros" in order to make the article searchable better?

Comment: This will produce page numbers that are at least two digits long. But that is not the same as having **separate digits** that can be manipulated and put in different table cells (which is what is attempted in the XSLT snippet in the question).

Comment: @mzjn That was actually my best guess what the OP was trying to accomplish :)

Comment: `master-name="mymaster"` is incorrect. It should be `master-reference="mymaster"`.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible.

`<fo:page-number/>` is a XSL-FO construct. It does not get a value until the XSL-FO processor runs. It cannot be manipulated in the XSLT stylesheet that generates the XSL-FO markup.